# nginx: back-reference matches from if() and rewrite at the same time

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

I need to translate following rule from apache to nginx:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} daily=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mobSpecCycle [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mobSpecTheme [NC]
RewriteRule ^rss\/mobSpec([^\/]+)/?$ /rss/mobSpec$1/mobSpec$1_%1.html
[QSA,NC,L]
```

which, e.g. rewrites

/rss/mobSpecArticle/?id=26422

into

/rss/mobSpecArticle/mobSpecArticle_26422.html

I started as follows

```
if ($args ~ id=([^&]*)|daily=([^&]*)) {
   rewrite ^/rss\/mobSpec([^\/]+)/?$ /rss/mobSpec$1/mobSpec$1_$2.html last;
}
```

However I don't know how to backrefernce id=([^&]*) in the rewrite rule?
I put $2 there, but it doesn't work... apache has %1 for
back-referencing matches from the RewriteCond.

1. How do I back-referencing matches from if () in nginx within
   following rewrite?
2. Any ideas how I can add the last two condition?

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mobSpecCycle [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mobSpecTheme [NC]`

Comment: You could use the predefined variables for the arguments, e.g. `$arg_id` and `$arg_daily`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some negative lookahead stuff in the regex in the rewrite rule, but I don't recommend it.

I suggest you rethink your approach rather than trying to repeat what you have.  Don't try to cram everything into one rewrite, and consider using `location` blocks more and `if` less.  I don't know the logic of your site well enough to really get this right, but consider something more like this:

```
location /rss/mobSpecCycle {
  ...
}
location /rss/mobSpecTheme {
  ...
}
location /rss/mobSpecArticle {
   rewrite /rss/mobSpecArticle/mobSpecArticle_$arg_id.html
}
location /rss/mobSpecDaily {
   rewrite /rss/mobSpecArticle/mobSpecArticle_$arg_daily.html
}
```

By all means use regex in your `location` blocks as needed (prefer that to using `if` statements), but the way you are covering both `id` and `daily` in one regex makes me think you are better to write something that follows the semantics of your site better.  It'll be more readable, and execute better than what you are doing at present.

If you really want to pursue your current approach, regex has the tools you need.

1. you can use PCRE's [named capture](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) .
2. your difficulty with your last two conditions could be dealt with using negative look-ahead assertions.

Be aware that most people looking at your configuration will be entirely unaware of these features of regex, and will be confused by them.  They can also become problematic for maintaining your own code, especially if you keep loading too much into one rewrite.

Comment: Thank you for all the introduced options! It seems indeed better to split it into several simple rules, however, why should one use a 3-line `location {}` block instead of a simple 1-line `rewrite ^/rss\/mobSpec([^\/]+)/?$ /rss/mobSpec$1/mobSpec$1_$arg_id.html last;` ?

Comment: Efficiency.  Nginx can go to the correct location block without treating the config like a series of conditionals to be gone through one by one till it find a match.  When it gets to the right location block, it can proceed using the roles inside that location block, and ignore almost everything outside the location block.